# ¿Deberia declarar variable escalar?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo un método creado en un `mapper` que uso para verificar el nombre de usuario y el password para un login, el código es el siguiente:

```
    public Usuario buscarUsuarioPorNombreYContrasenia(string xNombre, string xPass)
        {
            var param = new List<SqlParameter>();
            var nombre = new SqlParameter();
            var pass = new SqlParameter();
            nombre.ParameterName = "@nombreUsuario";
            nombre.Value = xNombre;
            param.Add(nombre);
            pass.ParameterName = "@pass";
            pass.Value = xPass;            
            param.Add(pass);
            var con = abrirConexion();
            var reader = select("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombreUsuario = @nombreUsuario AND pass = @pass",CommandType.Text,param,con,null);
 // Se cae pasando esta línea.
            Usuario u = null;
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    u = cargarUsuario(reader);

                }
                cerrarConexion(con);
                return u;     
            }
        }
```

En cuanto a la base de datos tengo lo siguiente, si hago la consulta en `SQL Server` entonces funciona y devuelve lo esperado pero en cambio en Visual me da ese error y lo raro es que ya he hecho esas consultas anteriormente y han funcionado, tal vez me estoy pasando algo por alto esta vez.

```sql
CREATE TABLE usuario(
idUsuario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
nombreUsuario VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
tipoUsuario BIT NOT NULL,
pass VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
)
```

Acá está lo que hace el método `Select`:

```
public static SqlDataReader select(string sentencia, CommandType tipoComando, List<SqlParameter> parametros, SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction trns)
{
    if(conn == null)
    {
        abrirConexion();
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = sentencia;
    cmd.CommandType = tipoComando;
    if(parametros == null)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray());
    }
    if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    if(trns != null)
    {
        cmd.Transaction = trns;
    }
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    return dr;            
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, incluye lo suficiente de tu código para que sea un [mcve].

Comment: @rn3w: Creo que el título era el mensaje de error que está recibiendo OP, aunque no lo ha hecho muy claro. En este caso, tal vez sea mejor dejarlo tal cual en vez de traducirlo.

Comment: esa función select que tiene adentro?  `var reader = select`

Comment: Porqué no haces un stored en la BD?, porqué estas haciendo el select directo en el código?

Comment: No estoy segura si se puede mandar `@nombreUsuario` directamente en el `select`.  Refiriendome a un parametro y no un valor en sí, en todo caso mejor manda: `"SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombreUsuario = '" + xNombre + "' AND pass = '" + xPass + "'"`

Comment: @sstan no me habria dado cuenta.

Comment: @sstan Sí, es el nombre del error que recibo pero no entiendo como es que decís que no está claro, ¿qué recomendarías que le agregara para que quede más completo? Ese es todo el código que tengo por ahora. Gracias, saludos.

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo Tengo otro método hecho que es un guardar para el cual uso los parámetros de la misma manera, es decir Var nombre = new SqlParameter();

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo tu sugerencia creo que funcionaría, aunque no es una muy buena práctica realizar consultas dinámicas ya que de esta forma es sucepticble a SQL Injection

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo apreté enter sin querer y ahora no puedo editar el comentario así que lo escribo de nuevo: Tengo otro método hecho que es un guardar para el cual uso los parámetros de la misma manera, y otro en el que lo que varía es que en vez de buscar x usuario busca a todos y me ha funcionado. Saludos.

Comment: hola, no se cual es el error que recibes.. perooooo esto esta mal:  if(parametros == null) y no se que son las llaves despues de Usuario u = null;

Comment: @Ccccccccc  Tienes razón con la inyección, pues si ya te funciona antes, tal vez no se están llamando igual los parámetros o algún otro error simple que no estas visualizando.  Podrías poner el SQL Profile y ver la transacción desde allí. Igual tienes la opción de crear el stored en la BD y llamarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La condición que determina cuando agregar los parámetros no está correcta:

```
if(parametros == null) // incorrecto
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray());
}
```

Obviamente, quisistes decir:

```
if(parametros != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray());
}
```

Tiene sentido que si nunca agregas los parámetros al objeto `cmd`, que te daría el error:

> Must declare the scalar

Comment: Hola, sí, era eso mismo, lo raro es que usé el mismo select para obtener todos los usuarios y sí me funcionó, ahora lo solucioné, la verdad que fue un error bastante pavo pero del que no me iba a dar cuenta, gracias por comentar a todos los que lo hicieron.